# WEBCAM sem Flash

Tags: javascript, html5-video, html5-canvas

Galera... Estou tentando tirar uma foto com uma webcam... sou relativamente novo em Javascript e estou levando um coro!

Segue meu código:

```js
   //função para iniciar a camera
   function startCamera(){
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
   video:{facingMode:'environment'},
   audio:true
      })
      .then((stream) => {
         document.getElementById('video').srcObject=stream
      })
   }
   //função para parar a camera
   function stopCamera(){
      document.getElementById('video')
      .srcObject
      .getVideoTracks()
      .forEach(track => track.stop())
   }
   //ligar a camer automaticamente
   window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startCamera())
   //função para tirar foto
    
   document.querySelector('#btnStart').addEventListener('click', event => {
      const canvas = document.getElementById('pic')
      const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
      const video = document.getElementById('video')
      //tamanho da foto mesmo tamanho do video
      canvas.width = video.offsetWidth
      canvas.height = video.offsetHeight
      //desenha o video no canvas
      context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.witdh, canvas.height)
      //metodo do canvas para pegar um objeto Blob
      canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
         const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
         stopCamera()
      }, 'image/jpeg', 0.95)
      //closeCamera()
   })
```

```html
   <video src="" id="video" muted autoplay></video>
   <canvas id="pic"></canvas>
  
   <input type="button" id="btnStart" value="Tirar Foto">
```

Até o momento só consegui ligar a câmera e aparecer o 'LIVE'... não consegui fazer a foto aparecer no canvas... fica toda preta a imagem quando clico no botão para tirar a foto.

Comment: Reverti a edição caro @reculos, porque se não descaracteriza a resposta, estou verificando o problema e já adiciono uma possivel resolução ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seu único erro é estar chamando a função na hora de declarar:

```
   window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startCamera())
```

O correto é o próprio `DOMContentLoaded` chamar, ficando assim:

```
   window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startCamera)
```

O outro erro é que a propriedade `srcObject` não é mais suportada desde [**Novembro de 2017**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement/srcObject), então deve usar algo como (para retro-compatibilidade):

```
try {
  video.srcObject = mediaSource;
} catch (error) {
  video.src = URL.createObjectURL(mediaSource);
}
```

Tem um erro de digitação simples também, você escreveu `witdh`:

```
 context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.witdh, canvas.height)
```

Mas o correto é `width`:

```
 context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
```

> Nota: movi todos eventos para dentro de `DOMContentLoaded`, tanto o `startCamera` quanto o click do botão.

Exemplo:

```js
   var tmpStream;

   function setMedia(video, s) {
      tmpStream = s;

      try {
        video.srcObject = s;
      } catch (error) {
        video.src = URL.createObjectURL(s);
      }
   }

   //função para iniciar a camera
   function startCamera(){
      navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
   video:{facingMode:'environment'},
   audio:true
      })
      .then((stream) => {
         setMedia(document.getElementById('video'), stream)
      })
   }
   //função para parar a camera
   function stopCamera(){
      //Se não tiver stream definido ainda
      if (!tmpStream) return;

      tmpStream.getVideoTracks().forEach(track => track.stop())
   }


   //inicia os eventos
   window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", startAll)

   function startAll()
   {
     //ligar a camera automaticamente
     startCamera()

     //função para tirar foto
     document.querySelector('#btnStart').addEventListener('click', event => {
        const canvas = document.getElementById('pic')
        const context = canvas.getContext('2d')
        const video = document.getElementById('video')
        //tamanho da foto mesmo tamanho do video
        canvas.width = video.offsetWidth
        canvas.height = video.offsetHeight
        //desenha o video no canvas
        context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        //metodo do canvas para pegar um objeto Blob
        canvas.toBlob(function(blob){
           const url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
           stopCamera()
        }, 'image/jpeg', 0.95)
        //closeCamera()
     })
   }
```

```html
   <video src="" id="video" muted autoplay></video>
   <canvas id="pic"></canvas>
  
   <input type="button" id="btnStart" value="Tirar Foto">
```

Comment: fiz as alterações... entendi o codigo... seria o mesmo que document.getElementById('video')=stream com tratamento de erro correto? entretanto, continua com o mesmo erro... a camer liga... aparece na tela o stream, quando clica no botão pra tirar a foto, o canvas vira um quadrado inteiro preto! não sei se estou certo, mas o problema está dentro do evendo 'click'... vou colocar o novo código acima! obrigado!

Comment: Caro @reculos `document.getElementById('video')=stream` parece incorreto, por isso criei a função, só pra constar, cameras acho que só rodam sob HTTPS, mas creio que em localhost também deva rodar, só em FILE:/// talvez não funcione, dependendo do navegador, vou testar bem aqui e corrigir qualquer erro possivel e te mando o código corrigido

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda @Guilherme Nascimento, tentei colocar em localhost e aqui mas também aconteceu a mesma coisa, depois de clicar no botão, virou um quadrado preto no lugar do canvas, entretanto o stream aparece na tela...

Comment: no firefox rodou... mas eu precisava que rodasse no chrome mesmo!

Comment: @reculos corrigido, era um erro de digitação simples, digitou `canvas.witdh`, mas o correto era `canvas.width`, aproveite e movi tudo para uma função unica para ser carregado tudo só quando a camera iniciar no DOMContentLoaded ;)

Comment: Boa @Guilherme Nascimento... Obrigado... funcionou perfeitamente!!!! qual IDE seria legal eu usar pra evitar este tipo de erro de digitação?

Comment: @reculos eu não uso IDE alguma, é mais pratica mesmo, se deixar algo semi-pronto ai só pra usar já ajuda, eu gosto muito inglês, então aprender a usar as propriedade e métodos das APIs e até escrever width faz parte disto, pessoalmente acho que ter um inglês de escrita no minimo é algo util em programação :)

Comment: sim concordo... perguntei pois foi um erro de digitação e não de inglês em si! um IDE que completa as palavras reservadas da programação ajuda a evitar erros de digitação! de qualquer forma, agradeço a ajuda... vou procurar ficar mais atento! rss

Comment: @reculos mas acho interessante isso também, aprender quais são as palavras "reservadas", afinal de contas dominar a linguagem e um pouco de inglês deveria ser o básico para subir a escada do aprimoramento como programador :) ... mas é opinião pessoas minha, mesmo sendo opinião minha gostaria de lhe indicar uma leitura: https://codingcraft.com.br/2016/06/01/nao-gosta-do-idioma-ingles-saia-da-programacao-isto-nao-e-para-voce/

Comment: acho que você não me entendeu... meu inglês é fluente... e também conheço as palavras reservadas... meu dedo que bateu sem querer a ordem errada das letras kkk